# Why can't I spend time in bed?

Tags: fallen-london

I'm a person of some importance who got quite badly wounded while studying the correspondence. I had some magnificent feasts while studying it to recuperate and get as much done as possible while I was in the mood and preternaturally intent, but now when I go to my lodgings I can't spend time in bed. I'd rather not die right now, so I'd like to do so.

Is there something that can block spending time in bed (and a way to unblock it) or should I contact tech support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the Lodging choices were reshuffled recently. Now options relating to each primary quality - Persuasive, Watchful, Dangerous and Shadowy have been gathered with options relating to the Menace that is associated with them - Scandal, Nightmare, Wounds and Suspicion respectively.

To heal your wounds simply look for the option that says "Attend to Matters of Danger and Wounds".

Comment: Ah good. Now I can rest.